# Como puedo guardar un archivo de formato Excel en formato pdf vba?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, pdf

Estoy utilizando visual basic pero para ello, el archivo de excel lo abro al inicio del programa pero quiero que se guarde como un pdf he trasteado un poco el codigo y he logrado esto pero me genera un pdf corrupto

```
    SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.pdf"
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "Nombre"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF(*.pdf)|*.pdf"
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Libro.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `SaveAs` guarda el archivo en formato Excel, para poder crear un PDF debes utilizar un método de exportación indicándole el formato (`Type`):

```
Dim path As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
Libro.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=path
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias me funciono correctamente este fue mi código final

```
    SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.pdf"
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "Nombre"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF(*.pdf)|*.pdf"
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim path As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    Libro.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, path)
```